# Why is this statement isn't working properly and always giving 'true'?

Tags: json, node.js, web-applications, server-side

This function is always returning true when trying to authenticate the user:

```
exports.IsUser = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.role === "user") {
        next();
    } else {
       return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized user!' });
    }
};
```

The json req.user:

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "fullName": "testname",
    "role": "user",
    "iat": 1502495033
}
```

the routing function:

```
app.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.json(req.user);})
    .post(control.IsUser);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `always giving true`?

Comment: I realized that app.route() does not go to the .post(control.IsUser); function to authenticate user, but resolving only the .get() callback function.